# Text in the div content does not appear properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my html code where the content does not appear in my div.
Tetxtarea, check box can be seen but what ever text I have written could not be seen.

also I have written css which should make the div in middle of screen which also does not place in center of screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Creating Popup Div | istockphp.com</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.center{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background:red;
    top:calc(50% - 50px/2);
    left:calc(50% - 50px/2);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="topopup">Click Here Trigger</a>


    <div id="toPopup" class="center"  style="background-color: #EDEFF1; height:300px;width:500px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px; moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;moz-border-radius-topright: 15px; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; ">

        <div class="close"></div>
        <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
        <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
        <p><b>Share post </b></p>
            <textarea style="height:65px;width:400px;">
            </textarea> <br>         
            <input type="checkbox"> - Facebook <hr> </input>
            <input type="checkbox"> - Twitter  <hr>
            <input type="checkbox"> - Linked in <hr>
            </br></br>                
        </div> <!--your content end-->    
    </div> 
</art>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/UD3U7/

On jsfiddle it shows the text. Actually the div should pop up rather directly appearing.
It could be seen on jsfiddle.

but on my localhost text in the div could not be seen.

Comment: provide a jsFiddle code of the relevant issue and not the full HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Check with this. For textarea the content between the open and close tags(Even a space) will be taken as content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Creating Popup Div | istockphp.com</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.center{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background:red;
    margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="topopup">Click Here Trigger</a>


    <div id="toPopup" class="center"  style="background-color: #EDEFF1; height:300px;width:500px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px; moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;moz-border-radius-topright: 15px; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; ">

        <div class="close"></div>
        <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
        <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
        <p><b>Share post </b></p>
            <textarea style="height:65px;width:400px;"></textarea> <br>         
            <input type="checkbox"> - Facebook <hr>
            <input type="checkbox"> - Twitter  <hr>
            <input type="checkbox"> - Linked in <hr>
            </br></br>                
        </div> <!--your content end-->    
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No improvement. Position changed but not in center yet. And also text is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean about "whatever text I have written could not be seen" but I've fixed your css and html to allow the popup div to be centered in the page.

If you have a CSS file then put all your styling in the CSS file. Don't use a mix of styling in the HTML and CSS because you'll have trouble debugging and maintaining your code.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ5rx/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="topopup">Click Here Trigger</a>

<div id="toPopup" class="center">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
    <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
        <p><b>Share post </b></p>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Enter comment..."></textarea> <br>

            <input type="checkbox"> - Facebook <hr> </input>
            <input type="checkbox"> - Twitter  <hr>
            <input type="checkbox"> - Linked in <hr>
            </br></br>

    </div> <!--your content end-->

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #EDEFF1; 
  height:300px;
  width:450px; 
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px; 
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px; 
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px; 
  moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
  moz-border-radius-topright: 15px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not quite sure why you can't see a text you have written in textarea, I can.
I'd suggest you to change the style on something like:

```
 .center{
        position: absolute;
        height:300px;
        width:500px;
        margin: -150px 0 0 -250px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        background-color: #EDEFF1;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
        border-top-right-radius: 15px;
        border-top-left-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    }
```

this should resolve the center issue and since you have a class with your style description, I'd suggest to put all styling options there, I mean

```
<div id="toPopup" class="center"  style="background-color: #EDEFF1; height:300px;width:500px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px; moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;moz-border-radius-topright: 15px; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; ">
```

should become just

```
<div id="toPopup" class="center"  >
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
position: absolute;
```

and add

```
margin:0 auto;
```

updated jsfiddle link :http://jsfiddle.net/UD3U7/3/